# How to not display the view automatically when calling regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion

Tags: wpf, prism

I'm developing a Prism (WPF) composite application that registers a view with a region using regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(). However, the view automatically displays in the region when the app launches. How can I tell Prism not to display the view at startup? I have a button that will do this if the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RegisterViewWithRegion, if you don't want the view to automatically appear in the region. I mean, that's what the function does.

If you want to put the view in the region by hand, use view injection (I.e. Call methods on the region/region manager), or navigation.

There is no requirement to register the view, unless you want the automatic "View Discovery" behaviour.